# cypher query: infinite loop with optional match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

today I was trying to expand a query that I'm running on a very small test database, but I think that I must be firing some kind of infinite loop, because it keeps executing until it returns an undefined error

so I have no idea what the problem is, and am looking for suggestions...

this query works

```
MATCH (n:whatnot), (u:user) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r1:favorites]->(n)

WHERE id(u)=1 

RETURN

  id(n) AS id ,
  CASE
    WHEN length((u)-[r1]->(n)) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS favorites

ORDER BY id DESC
```

and this works too

```
MATCH (n:whatnot), (u:user) , (m)

WHERE id(u)=1 AND id(m) = 73298 AND (n)-->(m)

RETURN id(n) AS id
```

but even thou they share results, if I try to run them together like so

```
MATCH (n:whatnot), (u:user) , (m)
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r1:favorites]->(n)

WHERE id(u)=1  AND id(m) = 73298 AND (n)-->(m)

RETURN

  id(n) AS id ,
  CASE
    WHEN length((u)-[r1]->(n)) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS favorites

ORDER BY id DESC
```

it goes into an infinite loop

what am I missing?

many thanks you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the WHERE for the top MATCH before the OPTIONAL MATCH. Also, it's better to do predicate patterns in the MATCH if you can.

```
MATCH (n:whatnot)-->(m), (u:user)
WHERE id(u)=1 AND id(m)=73298
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r1:favorites]->(n)
RETURN
  id(n) AS id ,
  CASE
    WHEN length((u)-[r1]->(n)) > 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS favorites
ORDER BY id DESC
```